# The convergence of $(n\sin n)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I  think $\lim_{n\to \infty} n\sin n$ does not exist, for $\sin x$ is a wave function and when $n\to \infty$, then so does factor $n$. But I am confused that how to give a strict proof for the divergence.

I would appreciate it if someone could give some suggestions and comments.

Comment: Try to find $\limsup_{x \to \infty} \sin (x)$

Comment: Please make it clear: If you use $n$ for the limit, it means $n$ approaching infinity along positive integers. Is that what you intended to say?

Comment: Even $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin n$ is divergent. But is bounded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every convergent sequence is bounded.

**Edit:** Let $m \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Then $$\sin x\geq \sin\left(\frac12\right)>0\,\, \forall x \in \left[\frac12+2m\pi,\frac32+2m\pi\right].$$ Moreover there exists $n_m \in \left[\frac12+2m\pi,\frac32+2m\pi\right] \cap \mathbb{N}.$ Therefore $$n_m\sin(n_m)\geq \left(\frac12+2m\pi\right)\sin\left(\frac12\right).$$It follows that $(n \sin n)_n$ is unbounded.

Comment: Great , you are right!

Comment: And why is this sequence not bounded?

Comment: As @zhw. points out, it's not that obvious that $(n\sin n)_n$ is unbounded... and that definitely requires a proof.

Comment: @zhw. I have added the reason.

Comment: @ClementC. OP's comment suggested that unboundedness wasn't a problem for them. I have added a proof anyway.

Comment: @Dr.Jacob.Z.Lee I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 4):

Given that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1 }{n} = 0$$ And $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin n$ doesn't exist, it's easy to prove that. The [former](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386596/using-the-definition-of-a-limit-to-prove-1-n-converges-to-zero) can be proved by the definition while the [latter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743360/showing-a-n-sinn-does-not-converge) with the proof by contradiction. Suppose  $$ \lim _{n \to \infty}n\sin n = L$$ So we have $$ \lim _{n \to \infty}n\sin n \times \frac{1}{n}= \lim _{n \to \infty} \sin n = 0$$
And this is a contradiction.

**Edit:** If we want to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin n$ doesn't exist, according to the Jonas Teuwen's answer in the mentioned page, suppose $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin n = l$. It's known that a sequence converges iff every subsequence converges. So $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin 2n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin 2(n+1) = l$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos2n = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1-2\sin^2 n = 1 - 2l^2$ and also $\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos2(n+1) = 1 - 2l^2$. Then $$\sin(2) = \sin(2(n+1) - 2n) = \sin(2(n+1))\cos(2n) - \sin(2n)\cos(2(n+1))$$Taking limit yields $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(2) = l\times (1-2l^2) - l\times (1-2l^2) = 0$$So this implies $$\sin(2) = 0$$ Which is clearly a contradiction.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin n}{n} \neq 1$.

Comment: @ClementC. Sorry for that. Is it correct now?

Comment: Looks good to me, under the assumption that $\lim \cos n$ doesn't exist is known/usable. (Also, you can use $L'=0$ at the end.)

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks for mentioning my silly mistake.

Comment: (+1) All too easy.

Comment: @MarkViola My pleasure.

Comment: Very quick and nice argument. The last line should be $\lim cos(2n)=1$.

Comment: @SungjinKim That's very kind of you, you're right. Actually I changed $\frac{\sin}{n}$ to $\frac{1}{n}$ which clearly is a better option for reaching to a contradiction.

Comment: We return to the question of whether $n$ goes to infinity through _integers_ only, or through real numbers. If through real numbers, sure, it is obvious that the limit does not exist. But if $n$ only runs through integers, at least some small result about the nature of $\pi$ (at least its size) is necessary, as in another answer.

Comment: @paulgarrett I think my answer shows the limit doesn't exist if $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If there is a mistake in that please say so that I improve that or remove if is necessary.

Comment: @S.H.W, true, but needs to be confirmed, that $\sin n$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ does not go to $0$. They don't, but _why_? It needs some property of $\pi$. Otherwise, with a function $f$ instead of $\sin$, periodic of period $1$ (rather than $2\pi$), vanishing at $0$, then it would vanish at _all_ integers. It's a small thing, and your conclusion is correct (of course), but there is this small potential hazard. Again, $\sin n$ for $n$ integer does not assume _all_ the values of $\sin$ (the range $[-1,1]$), but only a discrete subset... and some details about that subset must be clarified...

Comment: @paulgarrett Actually the link which I've provided shows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin n$ doesn't exist and it is proved by contradiction.

Comment: Mmm, I'd not want to have to depend on any argument written in that style... Better to redo it "from scratch", etc. It's not completely obvious, nor do I see why it should be "by contradiction". In such simple things, there is no reason to be vague or obscure, I think.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks, I added the proof.

Answer (score -2):

We have that $a_n = n \sin{(n)}$. Rewrite it during that $\sin{(x)}\in\left[-1,1\right]$:
$$-n\leq n \sin{(n)} \leq n$$
Than, using the lim:
$$-lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n \leq lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n \sin{(n)} \leq lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n$$
$$-\infty \leq lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n \sin{(n)} \leq \infty$$
This shows, that $a_n$ is unbounded and thats because limit does not exists:
$$\nexists lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n \sin{(n)}$$

Comment: Also, you can see that $a_n$ is unbounded if you plot the graph.

Comment: $-n \leq \frac1n \leq n \implies -\lim n \leq \lim \frac1n \leq \lim n \implies -\infty\leq \lim \frac1n \leq \infty \implies \frac1n$ is unbounded?

Comment: @SahibaArora It's unbounded on infinity. Maybe I can't fully understand word "unbounded" because English is not my native language.

Comment: Your proof does not show $(n \sin n)$ is unbounded. A sequence $(a_n)$ is said to be unbounded if for each $M >0,$ there exists $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n>M.$ Your proof suggests that if $-n \leq a_n \leq n,$ then $(a_n)$ is unbounded. This is not true, for example, if $a_n=\frac1n.$